# Android canvas remember previous paintings on invalidate

Tags: android, canvas

When using invalidate the history of previous drawing actions are gone. I want to create an animation where I draw some new pixels after a certain delay.

I have tried using a Bitmap to remember the previous set pixels, but it won't load on the canvas, it throws an exception, see code below (commented not working).

I tried using invalidate but it completely wipes out the previous set pixels.

```java
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int colorWhite = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.white);
        int colorBlack = getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black);

        //not working
        //Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(300,300, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        //canvas.setBitmap(bmp);

        try
        {
            if(board == null) {
                Ant ant = new Ant(new Position(430,430), new TurnDegree(0));
                board = new Board(ant, 15000);
                board.moveAnt();
            }

            MarkedPosition position = board.positions().get(count);
            if(position.isMarked()) {
                paint.setColor(colorWhite);
            } else {
                paint.setColor(colorBlack);
            }
            paint.setStrokeWidth(5);

            System.out.println(position.position().x());

            canvas.drawRect(position.position().x(), position.position().y(),
                    position.position().x() + 5, position.position().y() + 5, paint);

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    invalidate();
                }
            }, 100);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

        count++;
    }
```

How can I create a sort of animation which draws new pixels to the screen after a certain delay, without having to repaint all pixels which I set previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can store your previous pixels in ArrayList. after invalidate redraw all the points from ArrayList

make Arraylist of rect

```
ArrayList<Rect> allRects = new ArraList();
```

add when you draw rect on cavas

```
Rect rect = new Rect(position.position().x(), position.position().y(),
                    position.position().x() + 5, position.position().y() + 5);
canvas.drawRect(rect);
allRects.add(rect);
```

after invalidate again draw all rect using for loop

```
for (i = 0; i< allRects.size(); i++){
      canvas.drawRect(allRects.get(i));
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the screen turns white, because I have about 1 to 25000 pixels to draw each second.

Comment: Sorry, got some other heavy calculations in the loop.. this seems to be the answer.